# How to set padding equal to margin: auto?

Tags: html, css

I have a container that contains a navbar. The container has both padding and x-axis margin of auto being applied. I'm trying to build a navbar that has a shadow on the bottom which is the width of the full viewport. I want the content of the navbar to fit within the container so it would also have the same padding on both sides as the padding + margin of the container which contains it. Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Container:

```
padding: 80px;
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto;
```

Nav:

```
display: flex;
box-shadow: 0px 10px 8px -8px #00000024;
width: 100vw;
margin-left: calc((100% - 100vw) / 2);
```

Here's a simple codepen illustrating what I'm trying to do. https://codepen.io/jacksoncohen/pen/yLXPbZz

Comment: Auto margin on the x-axis just centers the contents, but in your example it does nothing because `<container>` children's width is full viewport. Do you want to center your `<nav>` element?

Comment: @FelipeSaldanha If you adjust the viewport then the auto margin is being applied and scaling based on the size of the viewport. I want the nav to have the same margin + padding as the container so the content will be aligned but the shadow below the nav will display along the entire viewport.

Comment: Auto margin is unrelated to the behavior you are describing. Could you please provide an image of what would be the result you are expecting?

Comment: @FelipeSaldanha Here are three images. In the [first one](https://i.imgur.com/r7BMP32.png), there is a small viewport which is not applying any margin- so the content of the nav and content line up because they each only have 80px of left and right padding. In the [second one](https://i.imgur.com/CyfDnRa.png), the viewport is slightly larger which has started to add some left and right margin from the margin auto that is applied. Now the content is no longer lined up. The [third image](https://i.imgur.com/ysCmgBF.png) displays this as well even more exaggerated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to touch your HTML, you can achieve the desired result by using `@media` and dynamically calculating the lateral padding. Note that you don't even have to use automatic margins:

**Option 1:**

```css
.nav,
.inner {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 80px;
}

.nav {
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 8px -8px lime;
  display: flex;
}

.nav-item {
  margin: 0 8px;
}

.inner-item {
  background: red;
  height: 20%;
  margin: 10px 8px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1440px) {
  .nav,
  .inner {
    padding: 0 calc(80px + (100vw - 1440px) / 2);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="nav">
      <div class="nav-item">Item 1</div>
      <div class="nav-item">Item 2</div>
      <div class="nav-item">Item 3</div>
      <div class="nav-item">Item 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class='inner'>
      <div class="inner-item">Item 1</div>
      <div class="inner-item">Item 2</div>
      <div class="inner-item">Item 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If you wrap your `<nav>` with another div, you can have a slightly simpler solution:

**Option 2:**

```css
.nav,
.inner {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 80px;
}

.nav-wrapper {
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 8px -8px lime;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1440px;
}

.nav-item {
  margin: 0 8px;
}

.inner {
  max-width: 1440px;
}

.inner-item {
  background: red;
  height: 20%;
  margin: 10px 8px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <div class="nav">
        <div class="nav-item">Item 1</div>
        <div class="nav-item">Item 2</div>
        <div class="nav-item">Item 3</div>
        <div class="nav-item">Item 4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='inner'>
      <div class="inner-item">Item 1</div>
      <div class="inner-item">Item 2</div>
      <div class="inner-item">Item 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

One last note: no container styles needed for both cases.